# inout with reg type in verilog

Tags: verilog, inout

I have used `inout` with `c`, but for `c` to be on the LHS of procedural assignment, it needs to be a `reg` type variable. Can anyone help me out with this code?

```
module multiedgeclk(input clk ,[7:0] a,b,d, inout [7:0] c, output reg [7:0]f); 
     always @(posedge clk)
          c <= a + b;
     always @(negedge clk)
          f = c & d;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4):

In verilog `inout` is the direction of the port. `wire` or `reg` is the type of the signal. 
If you want to drive a bi-directional port, it should be declare as `inout wire` or `inout` and drive it with enable signal
Here is a example of bi-directional port.

```
module ABC( inout [7:0] c );
reg [7:0] c_out;
reg out_en;
assign c = out_en ? 8'hz : c_out; 
/* something here
... 
*/
endmodule
```

Comment: is inout wire synthesizable?

Answer (score 4):

An `inout` port cannot be procedurally assigned. There is nothing to indicate how long to hold that value on the port. This is the problem for any `wire`. But wires have a strength mechanism for multiple continuous drivers, the highest strength wins. So you can use a continuous assignment to selectively drive a value or turn it off by driving a `z` value.

```
wire c;
reg c_reg;

assign c = c_reg;
```

Now you can procedurally assign `c_reg` to a value or `8'bz`

See my [article for more info about wires and reg types](http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg).

Comment: is inout wire synthesizable?

Comment: It depends. Generally, FPGA synthesis tools only support `inout` at the top level I/O port. Other cases depend on the target technology being synthesized.