# Bidirectional assignment in Systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, assign

I need to create mux block that works with inout pins.
My module has n inputs and n outputs, I want to be able to switch
between different outputs.

The problem that I am currently having is that I need to do that with 
inout pins. So if my output pin is pulled down, the input pin of the
mux shall see that. This doesn't work with a common assign statement since
it will only write in one direction. I have tried an alias statement, which
works like a bidirectional assign, but I can not combine this with an if statement for the mux.

What I want to do:

```
alias net_out = (config) ? net1 : net2;
```

I have created an example [on edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2zqJ)

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: to my taste, neither your question nor your example cleanly explain the problem which you trying to solve. That does it meant that the 'input' pin shell see that? how? In your example you can drive 'in1' with 'out2' to get 'x' in tb code. Why you did not do it? can you elaborate?

Comment: The x is only visible at the output pin, not at the input pin. If it is a bidirectional connection the x should also be visible at the input pin. The code in the example is unidirectional, you don't see x at the input pin.

Comment: Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821122/inout-with-reg-type-in-verilog/50821605#50821605) for bi-directional bus.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bidirectional `tran` primitives, which is exactly how one would implement this in MOS hardware.

```
tranif1(net_out, net1, config);
tranif0(net_out, net2, config);
```

If you are looking to do this in hardware, this has to be something your technology supports. Most FPGAs would not support this.

However, if this `config` signal was a parameter and not a variable, you could use the `alias` statement with a generate-if

```
if(config)
  alias net_out = net1;
else
  alias net_out = net2;
```